# What is the name of this "scroller"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a "scroller" like this website:
http://www.ultranoir.com/en/#!/projects/

(when you move the mouse to the right or left of the project list it will auto scroll). Another nice thing is that the speed also increases if you move further to the side(s))

I tried to google but haven't found anything really fit the bill so far.

Comment: [have a look here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/)

Answer (score 0):

A google search of "jQuery scrolling plugin" will yield bountiful results to help you achieve your desired UX. Veuve Cliquot implemented the exact plugin you need for about six months, as I recall.

As a coding autodidact who shat his pants before posting questions on stack, can I make a request that this place not turn into a repository for lazy questions and/or advertising links? If you're lazy, google it, and ctrl+c / ctrl+v until something works. Probably less efficient than learning how to do it yourself, but still not sullying these pristine, crystal, life-bearing waters with nonsense/promo questions.

If you want PR, go to PRNewsire or do the link-digging yourself by becoming a valuable contributor to stackoverflow. Otherwise, I hope that stackers who value the community will poop on comments like Kyle's.

Additionally, " X ".

That means suck it.

Comment: I spent lots of time searching, and I couldn't find what I want. In short, some don't have speed increasing when you move your mouse etc. Most implementations lack 1 or 2 things and I just want to know if there is a readily made solution so I dont have to reinvent the wheel. There is no PR here, and I did search but couldn't find what I want, that's it. Isn't SO the place supposed to be the place where people contribute what they know to help other save time. If you don't want to answer my question, just ignore it, why being so rude?